# Android exception related with the internet connection

Tags: android, json

My target is to retrieve JSON's through an android device. The code I used to succeed this, is the following one:

```
 public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    }
```

Unfortunately because i can't connect to the interner succesfully i receive the following error at the HttpResponse line:

java.lang.runtimeexception unable to start activity componentinfo: android.os.Network

I read in other threads here in Stackoverflow that a possible solution it will be to start a new thread. But i don't know how to do this.

P.S. I already have declared the internet permission line in the androidmanifest.xml i.e.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: If you cant connect to the network, whats the problem with your exception?  Just handle it somehow - give the user the option of retrying etc etc.  If you are running that code on the main UI thread, you need to readup on async programming in Android a bit more.  ASyncTask is a helper class that (under the hood) creates a new thread for you but saves you from actually knowing much about threading.  See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). You do need to know about Java gereric's though ;o)

Comment: have you tried embedding your code in an AsyncTask class?

Comment: i'm newbie in android. so no i didn't try it.can anyone give some directions?

Comment: You should post the full stack trace of your exception (in this case including at the very least the inner exception). Also, if this does turn out to be a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` there are numerous other StackOverflow questions and answers that address this in conjunction with `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class i wrote to query data from a server(Google app engine), it makes a connection and goes and reads something online.

```
public class QueryServer 
{ 
    public static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8888/";

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
    {           
        String output = null;           
        try
        {               
             for (String url : urls) 
             {                      
                output = getOutputFromUrl(url); 
                Log.d("Server Return", output);
             }               
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Exception", e.getMessage());
        }
        return output;
    }           
  } 
  private String getOutputFromUrl(String url)
  {
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer("");
        try 
        {
            InputStream stream = getHttpConnection(url);
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            String s = "";
            while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
            {
                output.append(s);
                output.toString();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output.toString();
    } 
    // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
    private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException 
    {
        InputStream stream = null;
        try 
        {                
            java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(urlString);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();      
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) 
            {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream;
    } 
    protected void onPostExecute(String output) 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: since you are using JSON, declare the 'getOutputFromUrl' method as a JSON and not a string...hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
                 JSONObject j = null;
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            //HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
           // is = httpEntity.getContent(); 
            j = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()));

        }finally{
                     return j;
                }
}
```